# xcode/objective-c Calling instance methods

Tags: objective-c, class, methods, instance

**this problem's been solved, thanks for your help**

So I'm trying to teach myself xcode for programming iphone/ipod apps by writing an app and looking up what I need to know as I need to know it. This website has probably been the biggest help but this time I haven't been able to find an answer to my problem, probably because it's too simple for anyone who has a book to have asked.

I'm trying to create an app that will draw ten cards at random from a deck of 25. I made a class called Dealer that has all of the cards and an array that holds a reference to each of them as member data, as well as a method that returns a card from the array and removes it. here's my code for the method

```
- (NSString *)drawDominion
{
    //some code here

    NSString *current = [dominionDeck objectAtIndex:i];

    //more irrelevant code

    return current;
}
```

Then in an action method for my View Controller I created an object of my class and tried calling drawDominion but it's giving me the error "Receiver type 'Dealer' for instance message does not declare a method with selector 'drawDominion'

```
- (IBAction) Dominion
{
    Dealer *deal = [[Dealer alloc] init];
    NSString *testStr = [deal drawDominion];
}
```

here's the code where I tried calling drawDominion. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here, I just picked up xcode yesterday and it's been an uphill battle since then. thanks for any help you can offer.

in answer to some of your replys:
Well I didn't make a Dealer.h  but I kinda piggy-backed the interface for it in the existing viewController.h could that be causing my problem? it starts after the @end for the class already defined in there and it looks like this.

```
@interface Dealer : NSObject

-(NSString *) drawDominion:(NSString**)array;
-(NSString *) drawIntrigue:(NSString**)array;
-(NSString *) drawBoth:(NSString**)array;

@end
```

also I guess I forgot to put the instance variables in the .h but the compiler doesn't seem to be complaining about that. should I put them in there anyway?

Comment: Where are you actually calling the methods to draw the string?

Comment: Have you declared the method in the Dealer.h file? Have you imported the Dealer.h file into your viewController?

Comment: This code only is supposed to work, but there are many points to check (initializers, gui, ...). Did you try logging `testStr` ?

Comment: In your drawDomain method, make sure you do [[current retain] autorelease]; BEFORE you remove it from domainDeck. Otherwise, if domainDeck was the last thing that had a reference to the object, it will be destroyed, and you will return a bad pointer. This is not a problem if you are using ARC.

Comment: well to take the card out of the array I was just setting its spot equal to nil. I'm sure my code isn't the most graceful way of going about it but it is my second day with xcode. changing a position in the array to nil wouldn't cause a memory leak would it?

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the prototype for the drawDominion method to Dealer.h ? You should have something like

```
@interface Dealer : NSObject {
  // instance variables here
}
-(NSString*)drawDominion;
@end
```

In Dealer.h
Then when you #import "Dealer.h" the compiler knows that a Dealer will  have a drawDominion method.

Comment: Well I didn't make a Dealer.h  but I kinda piggy-backed the interface for it in the existing viewController.h could that be causing my problem? it starts after the @end for the class already defined in there and it looks like this.

Comment: whoops, I messed up that comment, I edited the answer into my original post though

Comment: Thanks for your help, turns out I forgot to take the parameters out of the .h definition when I changed the methods. Sorry for wasting your time.